# Synchronize operations inside a for loop

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiimageview, synchronization, nsarray

I'm using the `QBImagePickerController`library to select more than one image in the provided Image Picker view.
I want to let the user upload more than a single image to the "main" server, with a `UIImageView` displaying what is uploaded at the moment and a `UIProgressView`.

Since

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(QBImagePickerController *)imagePickerController didSelectAssets:(NSArray *)assets
```

give me an array of `ALAssets` containig all the images the user selected, I iterate through it this way:

```
NSMutableArray *IDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if([assets count] == 1) {
    // single image, no prob.
} else {

    for(ALAsset *a in assets) {
        //set the image to the one which is uploaded right now
        //upload it through a library and tell about status with NSProgress
        //write the result into IDs
    }
}
```

My problem is that if the user select two images, the operations appears to be running at the same time, so the `UIProgressView` is uploaded in what seems a "first come, first served" scenario, while the `UIImageView`shows only the last image selected and `IDs` seems empty.

Is this behaviour due to the method I use to iterate through the array?

What can I do to make each operation mutually exclusive?

Comment: Most likely, the library uses a background thread to do the upload, while periodically updating the progress view. So the loop just starts all of the uploads, without waiting for any to finish. Does the library have a mechanism that indicates that an upload is finished, e.g. a completion handler or delegate method?

Comment: The only method to see informations about the upload status is through `NSProgress`.

Comment: Hmm, that means using [Key-Value Observing (KVO)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) to monitor the progress and determine when each upload is finished. I haven't used `NSProgress`, so I'm afraid I can't be any more specific.

Comment: Of course I'm using it, otherwise I cannot update the progress bar. I'll see if this library uses any kind of backgrounding.